# Winform utilizing progress bar and file copying

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a form with a publish button, a cancel button, a label, and a progress bar.  When I click the button, all the files that are needed to get copied to a different directory gets copied over.  This part works fine.  I'm now utilizing a progress bar to let a user know what file is being published at any given time.  That way, if something goes wrong or a file is really big, the user knows what file is causing the problem (via the label).  The files are populated through a list of strings.  Originally, I was just using the Thread.Sleep to make the process longer than a split second of copying files.  However, just using that prevents interaction with the UI (such as if a user wants to cancel).  So I'm using BackgroundWorker to accomplish my problem.

**What I expect to happen when clicking "publish"**

Label tells me "Starting publication...".  After each file, the progressbar value increments, the label indicates the file that's being published, when copying is over, label says "Publish Complete", progressbar value is maxed.

**What DOESN'T happen**

The label doesn't update for the files.  It just says "Starting publication" then "Publish Complete".

**Question**

How do I "ReportProgress" correctly so I can update my label after each file is being copied?

**Code**

```
   private void btnPublish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                
                ProgressBar();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Data.Common.ErrorHandling.DisplayError(ex);
            }
        }



private void ProgressBar()
        {
            lblPublish.Text = "Starting publication...";
            //DoWork
            if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }




 private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        }
    }


  private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> allAcros = NumOfTotalAcros();
        foreach (var acro in allAcros)
        {
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(allAcros.IndexOf(acro));
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
                return;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> acros = new List<string>();
        cdsPublishBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        for (int i = 0; i < acros.Count; i++)
        {
            lblPublish.Text = "Processing " + acros[i].ToString() + "...";
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            lblPublish.Text = "Processing cancelled";
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            lblPublish.Text = e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            cdsPublishBar.Value = 100;
           lblPublish.Text = "Publish Complete";

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you want `List<string> acros = new List<string>();` in your _ProgressChanged method. The List acros is length 0, so the for loop is iterating over nothing.

Comment: @WilliamMoore I just noticed that after you posted.  I defined it correctly elsewhere but not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new *empty* collection that has no relation to the collection in the `DoWork` event, and then iterating over it... which will never print anything.

```
// empty list
List<string> acros = new List<string>();

// no elements to iterate over
for (int i = 0; i < acros.Count; i++)
{
    lblPublish.Text = "Processing " + acros[i].ToString() + "...";
}
```

Instead, pass the values you need via `ReportProgress`'s second parameter:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, acro);
```

And then use that in the `ProgressChanged` method:

```
cdsPublishBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
lblPublish.Text = string.Format("Processing {0}...", e.UserState);
```

Comment: Thanks man.  Yeah , I didn't catch the empty list part.  Also something I didn't add was setting the progress bar max to the size of the list (rather than default 100) and incremement it by one in the progress changed (instead of (e.ProgressPercentage).